Why I can't access state in window event handler?
I started learing react.js and developing a personal project now. I faced an issue and can't find what's wrong.
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleScroll = () => {
        const { scrollHeight, clientHeight } = document.documentElement;

        console.log(open);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, []);

I set window scroll event handler and in handleScroll function, I want to show changing of open state. But it always shows me false even if I already changed it. Please help me what's wrong.
I tried to pass open state to handleScroll, but it's not working.

Look into "stale closures". Your event listener is calling the original handleScroll function from the initial mount which closes over (ie: only has visibility) of the state from the initial mount.

For example: How to pass in a dynamic parameter to a function inside of a addEventListener scroll as it seems to get memoized? - You can also look into using the experimental hook useEffectEvent() if you don't want to recreate the event listener every time open changes.

Thanks Nick. It's very helpful for me and I see what I didn't know in this problem. Again, Thank you.

I find it ironic that you've done an eslint-disable, presumably to silence the warning about the unused handleScroll dependency - when adding that dependency (particularly if you then wrap handleScroll in a usecallback that depends on open, so you don't have a new handleScroll on every single render but just when the open state changes) would exactly solve your problem. I highly recommend never leaving off depencies in useEffect and related hooks.

I saw your problem and I have an idea.
When the component renders, it creates handleScroll function.
And after that, handleScroll function becomes a closure. So even you try to change it (setOpen(true) - like this), it is impossible. handleScroll function still refers to 'false' because 'open' is part of the closure.
So you should use 'useCallback' hook to change the value.
Code I wrote below can change the value of open when you click button.
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

const handleScroll = useCallback(() => {
    const { scrollHeight, clientHeight } = document.documentElement;

    console.log(open);
}, [open]);

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
}, [handleScroll]);

return (
    <button onClick={() => setOpen(true)} >Click</button>
);

I hope this code will be helpful for you!
